# TURTLES-ON expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the number 0 instead

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a model that is supposed to carry out an action if there are any turtles on a specific patch. This is the area in which the error occurs. "counter" is my patch, and increasing the food supply is what the said action is.

```
if any? turtles-on counter
  [set food food + 1]
```

How can I change this so that it does not crash when there are no turtles (number 0) on the counter?

Comment: can you also show us the code where you set the variable named 'counter' to be a patch?

Answer (score 1):

If counter is truly not a numeric value except for this edge case, the below explicit check for 0 works.

```
if counter != 0 and any? turtles-on counter
  [set food food + 1]
```

Comment: I suspect assigning a patch to the counter variable is where it is failing, so there's no patch to count turtles-on, because that's the only way to get the error

Comment: @JenB I agree; the above is on the off chance they have a both types (0 is assigned when no patches are available; otherwise a patch is assigned).